# The width of a table not well with "tabularx" in LaTeX

Tags: tables, tabularx, alignment

I wanted to make a table's width as text width. So I did so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \caption{2018 water quality table}
  \label{2018 water quality table}
  \sisetup{table-alignment-mode = format,
  table-number-alignment = center,
  }
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
      c
      S[table-format = 2.1]
        S[table-format = 2.1]
        S[table-format = 2.1]
          S[table-format = 1.1]
          S[table-format = 2]
            c
            @{\extracolsep{\fill}}}
      \toprule
        \multirow{2}{*}{number} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\num{2018}Year~\num{0}\num{7}Month~\num{0}\num{9}Day~to~\num{2018}Year~\num{0}\num{7}Month~\num{13}day  water quality} & \multirow{2}{*}{Werther} \\ \cmidrule{2-6}
                            & $\mathrm{COD}_\mathrm{cr}$\tnote{1}  & $\mathrm{BOD}_\mathrm{5}$\tnote{2}  & NN &TP\tnote{3} &{SS}\tnote{4}\\
      \midrule
        1                   & 73        & 22.3      & 21.4      & 3.7      & 52     & sun              \\
        2                   & 69        & 18.9      & 11        & 1.3      & 28     & sun                 \\
        3                   & 80        & 29.1      & 10.8      & 1.3      & 37     & sun                \\
        4                   & 78        & 26        & 10.8      & 1.4      & 30     & sun                 \\
        5                   & 72        & 19.4      & 10.4      & 1        & 33     & sun              \\
       average                & 74.4      & 23.1      & 12.8      & 1.7      & 36 
          &                 \\
    \bottomrule       
  \end{tabularx}
  \begin{tablenotes}
    \footnotesize
    \item[1] S1
    \item[2] S2
    \item[3] S3
    \item[4] S4
  \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The effect was:
[image]

You can see the sixth column is too wide. The `tabularx` package can make each column distributed well, but why it didn't here?

And I have another table that did well in distribution horizontally:

```
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{test1}
  \label{tab:test2}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lcccccc@       {\extracolsep{\fill}}}
        \toprule
         & $\mathrm{COD}_\mathrm{cr}$  & $\mathrm{BOD}_\mathrm{5}$   & NN\tnote{1}     & TP     & SS     & pH       \\ \midrule
         test4    & \num{\le 80}    & \num{\le 13}     & \num{\le 25}    & \num{\le 2.0}   & \num{\le 40}    & \num{6}--\num{9}  \\
        test5 & \num{\le 50}   & \num{\le 5}     & \num{\le 10}   & \num{\le 0.5}   & \num{\le 10}   & \num{6}--\num{9} \\
        test6     & \SI{37.5}{\%}& \SI{61.5}{\%} & \SI{60.0}{\%} & \SI{75.0}{\%} & \SI{75.0}{\%} &          \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: tabularx adjusts the widths of `X` columns, using it as here with no X column ii can not do anything useful.

Comment: but rather than use tabularx I would use a two-line heading so that the heading is not wider than the data. tabularx is for adjusing _line breaking of text paragraphs_ in tables, it is less useful in numerical data tables.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The second table is distributed well without any `X`.

Comment: The second table is in error, that is just a standard `tabular*` (which `tabularx` uses internally) and that is stretching it out (for no reason, it just makes it harder to read) not (as you need here) forcing the columns closer together). Try with `tabularx` package and changing `tabularx` to `tabular*`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tested `tabularx` and `tabular*` of the second table and I found they are the same. Is there a way to combine `S` of `siunitx` and `X` of `tabularx` together. In such cases I can align numbers with decimal and make the table wide as I want.

Comment: The easiest way is just to use a wider format eg 4.8 insead of 2.1 in the S column spec then the column will be wide enough for 9999.12345678

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My god! I see the author of `tabularx` is you! I can't imagine one day I can communicate with so great people.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  You are so smart. I will write this skill in my book.

Comment: In `S` model, is better to use `tabularx` or `tabula*`? Frankly, I can't tell the difference between them. @DavidCarlisle

Comment: never use tabularx without an X

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay, I will remember this.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by writing `\num{2018}Year~\num{0}\num{7}Month~\num{0}\num{9}Day~to~\num{2018}Year~\num{0}\num{7}Month~\num{13}day`?

Comment: @Mico In my original table that is in Chinese. but in this line, the text is still long enough to make the table not in a good view. For making the questions suited here, I changed Chinese to English. What I did is to make that line enough long to make columns' width not good.

Comment: @Y.zeng - I just posted an answer, in which I moved that line into the interior of the table, where it seems to be placed much more happily.

Comment: @Mico Yes, you are right. That text should be moved into the table.   I never thought about this before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the possible correct code for the both table is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx, threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}

\begin{document}
First table:
    \begin{table}[ht]
\sisetup{table-format=2.1,
         table-column-width=3.8em}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{2018 water quality table}
\label{2018 water quality table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
      c SSS
        S[table-format = 1.1]
        S[table-format = 2]
    X
                                }
    \toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{number} 
    &   \multicolumn{5}{c}{water qualityin perios 2018.07.o9 to 2018.07.13} 
                        &   \multirow{2}{*}{Werther}\\ 
    \cmidrule{2-6}
    &   {$\mathrm{COD}_\mathrm{cr}$\tnote{1}}  
        &   {$\mathrm{BOD}_\mathrm{5}$\tnote{2}}  
            &   {NN}
                &   {TP\tnote{3}} 
                    &   {SS\tnote{4}}
                        &                           \\
      \midrule
1   & 73    & 22.3  & 21.4  & 3.7   & 52    & sun   \\
2   & 69    & 18.9  & 11    & 1.3   & 28    & sun   \\
3   & 80    & 29.1  & 10.8  & 1.3   & 37    & sun   \\
4   & 78    & 26    & 10.8  & 1.4   & 30    & sun   \\
5   & 72    & 19.4  & 10.4  & 1     & 33    & sun   \\
average
    & 74.4  & 23.1  & 12.8  & 1.7   & 36    &       \\
    \bottomrule
      \end{tabularx}\footnotesize
      \begin{tablenotes}
\item[1] S1
\item[2] S2
\item[3] S3
\item[4] S4
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
    
Second table
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{test1}
\label{tab:test2}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l*{6}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}       
    \toprule
    &   $\mathrm{COD}_\mathrm{cr}$  
        &   $\mathrm{BOD}_\mathrm{5}$   
            &   NN\tnote{1}     
                &   TP
                    &   SS
                        & pH       \\ \midrule
test4   & \num{\le 80}  & \num{\le 13}  & \num{\le 25}  
        & \num{\le 2.0} & \num{\le 40}  & \numrange{6}{9}   \\
test5   & \num{\le 50}  & \num{\le 5}   & \num{\le 10}   
        & \num{\le 0.5} & \num{\le 10}  & \numrange{6}{9}   \\
test6   & \qty{37.5}{\%}    & \qty{61.5}{\%}    & \qty{60.0}{\%} 
        & \qty{75.0}{\%}    & \qty{75.0}{\%}    &           \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Note:**
The second table, as is written in your question, works by accident.

[image]

**Edit:**
Simpler code with better control (without manual tweaking) over column width enable the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
First table:
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {2018 water quality table},
  label = {2018 water quality table},
note{1} = {S1},
note{2} = {S2},
note{3} = {S3},
note{4} = {S4}
                ]{colspec={X[c]
                      *{3}{X[c, si={table-format=2.1}]}
                           X[c, si={table-format=1.1}]
                           X[c, si={table-format=2.0}]
                           X[c]}
                 }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    number   
    &   \SetCell[c=5]{c}
        {{{water quality in periode 2018.07.09 to 2018.07.13}}} 
        &   &   &   &   &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}    {{{Wether}}}    
                                                    \\ 
    \cmidrule{2-6}
    &   {{{$\mathrm{COD}_\mathrm{cr}$}}}\TblrNote{1}  
        &   {{{$\mathrm{BOD}_\mathrm{5}$}}}\TblrNote{2}  
            &   {{{NN}}}
                &   {{{TP}}}\TblrNote{3}
                    &   {{{SS}}}\TblrNote{5}
                        &                           \\
      \midrule
1   & 73    & 22.3  & 21.4  & 3.7   & 52    & sun   \\
2   & 69    & 18.9  & 11    & 1.3   & 28    & sun   \\
3   & 80    & 29.1  & 10.8  & 1.3   & 37    & sun   \\
4   & 78    & 26    & 10.8  & 1.4   & 30    & sun   \\
5   & 72    & 19.4  & 10.4  & 1     & 33    & sun   \\
average
    & 74.4  & 23.1  & 12.8  & 1.7   & 36    &       \\
    \bottomrule
      \end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
    
Second table
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{test1}
\label{tab:test2}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={l *{6}{X[c]}}}
    \toprule
    &   $\mathrm{COD}_\mathrm{cr}$  
        &   $\mathrm{BOD}_\mathrm{5}$   
            &   NN    
                &   TP
                    &   SS
                        & pH       \\ \midrule
test4   & \num{\le 80}      & \num{\le 13}      & \num{\le 25}  
        & \num{\le 2.0}     & \num{\le 40}      & \numrange{6}{9}   \\
test5   & \num{\le 50}      & \num{\le 5}       & \num{\le 10}   
        & \num{\le 0.5}     & \num{\le 10}      & \numrange{6}{9}   \\
test6   & \qty{37.5}{\%}    & \qty{61.5}{\%}    & \qty{60.0}{\%} 
        & \qty{75.0}{\%}    & \qty{75.0}{\%}    &           \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
Regarding your comments:

- Partly you are right: width of column "SS" can become wider, if you not change `talltblr` settings. In such cases had to be added to table option  `hspan=minimal`:

```
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {2918 water quality},
  label = {2018 water quality table},
note{1} = {S1},
note{2} = {S2},
note{3} = {S3},
note{4} = {S4}
                ]{colspec={X[c]
                      *{3}{X[c, si={table-format=2.1}]}
                           X[c, si={table-format=1.1}]
                           X[c, si={table-format=2.0}]
                           X[c]},
                 hspan=minimal  % <---
                 }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    number
    &   \SetCell[c=5]{c}
        {{{water quality in periode 2018.07.09 to 2018.07.13\\ test by gjlksjlfd}}}
        &   &   &   &   &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}    {{{Wether}}}    \\
    \cmidrule{2-6}
    &   {{{$\mathrm{COD}_\mathrm{cr}$}}}\TblrNote{1}  
        &   {{{$\mathrm{BOD}_\mathrm{5}$}}}\TblrNote{2}  
            &   {{{NN}}}
                &   {{{TP}}}\TblrNote{3}
                    &   {{{SS}}}\TblrNote{5}
                        &  {{{Wether}}}             \\
      \midrule
% table body
    \bottomrule
    \end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
```

[image]

- However, I would rethinking, if the first row in your table is really necessary. For example, this information can be rephrased and moved to caption. By stealing  notation for time period and tables notes from nice @Mico answer (+1) and adding `caption` package for nice placement of caption above second table, the MWE can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
First table:
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {MacAuthor test of water quality in period 7--13 July, 2018},
  label = {2018 water quality table},
note{ } = {\textsuperscript{1} S1,
           \textsuperscript{2} S2,
           \textsuperscript{3} S3,
           \textsuperscript{4} S4}
                ]{colspec={X[c]
                      *{3}{X[c, si={table-format=2.1}]}
                           X[c, si={table-format=1.1}]
                           X[c, si={table-format=2.0}]
                           X[c]}
                 }
    \toprule
number
    &   {{{$\mathrm{COD}_\mathrm{cr}$}}}\TblrNote{1}
        &   {{{$\mathrm{BOD}_\mathrm{5}$}}}\TblrNote{2}
            &   {{{NN}}}
                &   {{{TP}}}\TblrNote{3}
                    &   {{{SS}}}\TblrNote{5}
                        &  {{{Wether}}}             \\
      \midrule
1   & 73    & 22.3  & 21.4  & 3.7   & 52    & sun   \\
2   & 69    & 18.9  & 11    & 1.3   & 28    & sun   \\
3   & 80    & 29.1  & 10.8  & 1.3   & 37    & sun   \\
4   & 78    & 26    & 10.8  & 1.4   & 30    & sun   \\
5   & 72    & 19.4  & 10.4  & 1     & 33    & sun   \\
average
    & 74.4  & 23.1  & 12.8  & 1.7   & 36    &       \\
    \bottomrule
      \end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
    
Second table
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{test1}
\label{tab:test2}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={l *{6}{X[c]}}}
    \toprule
    &   $\mathrm{COD}_\mathrm{cr}$  
        &   $\mathrm{BOD}_\mathrm{5}$   
            &   NN    
                &   TP
                    &   SS
                        & pH       \\ \midrule
test4   & \num{\le 80}      & \num{\le 13}      & \num{\le 25}  
        & \num{\le 2.0}     & \num{\le 40}      & \numrange{6}{9}   \\
test5   & \num{\le 50}      & \num{\le 5}       & \num{\le 10}   
        & \num{\le 0.5}     & \num{\le 10}      & \numrange{6}{9}   \\
test6   & \qty{37.5}{\%}    & \qty{61.5}{\%}    & \qty{60.0}{\%} 
        & \qty{75.0}{\%}    & \qty{75.0}{\%}    &           \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, in you second paragraph of codes, I change `water quality in periode 2018.07.09 to 2018.07.13` to 'water quality in periode 2018.07.09 to 2018.07.13\\ test by gjlksjlfd'. Then the table changes to weird. Is there a way to adjust the table?

Comment: Changing `water quality in periode 2018.07.09 to 2018.07.13` to `water quality in periode 2018.07.09 to 2018.07.13\\ test by gjlksjlfd` is just a case in which the `SS` column is too wide.

Comment: @Y.zeng, in which sense is "weird"? I would (according to my taste) move most of row text to caption. So the caption would be: "Water quality in periode 2018.07.09 to 2018.07.13 tested by gjlksjlfd" and in the first row keep only "water quality" if necessary or even better, remove this row. Bear in mind that I don't know background of your article and intention what you like to tell with this table.

Comment: Hello, the key question is: When there are `multirow` and  `multicolumn`,  the `multicolumn` is too wide which makes the columns under the `multicolumn` not have the same widths in `S` model and `tabularx` model to keep the table align as `\textwidth` and `decimal`.

Comment: May you fell the second table caption is too close to the `toprule`?

Comment: @Y.zeng, please see addendum to my answer. Hopefully it contain all desired changes and explanation. However, answer now become quite length ;-)

Comment: Thanks. You totally solve all problems with this table!

Comment: Hello, why you always use `{{{}}}`? Is it not suit to use `{}`?

Comment: @Y.zeng, because this is `tabularray` syntax requirement. See package documentation, subsection *5.5 Library siunitx*, pp 46 -- 47.

Comment: But I tested. One `{}` or no `{}` can do it too.

Comment: In your addendum, there is no need to add `{}` between `&` and `&`.

Comment: @Y.zeng, which table you tested* Tables based on `tabularray` package has such requirement. If you discover that this is bot true, than please inform package author, that he wrote wrong instruction in package documentation (about I doubt). If your test works, that this work by accident.

Comment: I have informed the package author who may be Chinese like me.

Answer (score 2):

Since none of the cells require automatic line breaking, I'd use a `tabular*` environment, *not* a `tabularx` environment.

I'd also structure the material differently, so that the line "Period: 7--13 July, 2018" is placed in the interior of the table instead of in the header, where it doesn't seem to belong anyway.

Oh, when using a `threeparttable` environment, please place the `\caption` and `\label` directives *inside* the `threeparttable` environment. (The three formal parts of a `threeparttable` environment are the caption, a tabular-like environment, and a `tablenotes` environment.)

I commented out the `\sisetup` instruction as it doesn't appear to be doing anything useful -- at least, not for the table at hand.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[flushleft,para]{threeparttable} % 'para' option is optional
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for 'S' column type
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
%  \sisetup{table-alignment-mode = format,
%  table-number-alignment = center,
%  }
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out intercolumn whitespace
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{2018 water quality table}
  \label{tab:2018_water_quality}
 
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
      c
      *{3}{S[table-format = 2.1]}
      S[table-format = 1.1]
      S[table-format = 2]
      c }
  \toprule
  Number 
  & {$\mathrm{COD}_\mathrm{cr}$\tnote{1}}  
  & {$\mathrm{BOD}_\mathrm{5}$\tnote{2}}  
  & {NN} 
  & {TP\tnote{3}} 
  & {{SS}\tnote{4}}
  & {Weather} \\
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{Period: 7--13 July, 2018} \\[0.5ex]
  1           & 73   & 22.3 & 21.4 & 3.7 & 52     & sun \\
  2           & 69   & 18.9 & 11   & 1.3 & 28     & sun \\
  3           & 80   & 29.1 & 10.8 & 1.3 & 37     & sun \\
  4           & 78   & 26   & 10.8 & 1.4 & 30     & sun \\
  5           & 72   & 19.4 & 10.4 & 1   & 33     & sun \\[0.5ex]
  average     & 74.4 & 23.1 & 12.8 & 1.7 & 36     & \\
  \bottomrule       
  \end{tabular*}
  
  \smallskip
  \begin{tablenotes}
    \footnotesize
    \item[1] S1
    \item[2] S2
    \item[3] S3
    \item[4] S4
  \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, may you take the time to teach me two things: `0.5ex` for what? I don't know what `0.5ex` means. Why in your case the `\item[1]` to `item[4]`  is arranged horizontally, but in my case they were arranged vertically?

Comment: @Y.zeng - The `[0.5ex]` particle instructs LaTeX to insert extra vertical whitespace, in the amount of `0.5ex`, after the line in question. Here, `ex` is a typographic length unit. Traditionally, `1ex` is the height of the lowercase letter `x`. (Easy to remember, isn't it?) The table notes are typeset inline because I loaded the `threeparttable` package with the option `para`.

Comment: `[0.5ex]` inserts extra vertical whitespace on top, bottom or both? Is `para` meaning `paragraph`?

Comment: @Y.zeng - The extra whitespace (in the amount of 0.5ex, say) is inserted *below* the current row.(Aside: You should be able to address your own question on your own, by playing around a bit with the sample code above and seeing what happens if you replace `[0.5ex]` with, e.g., `[5ex]`.) I don't claim to have any special insights into the linguistic preferences of the person who wrote the `threeparttable` package; the assumption that "para" is short for "paragraph" seems quite reasonable.

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. I will check that package soon.